# Google scripts. Google sheets add-ons

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть простое дополнение для google sheets, нужно в него передать данные с таблицы. В частности хочу передать количество заполненных колонок в дополнение, чтобы пользователь смог выбрать нужную колонку.

[image: Скрин дополнения]

Вот код на google scripts, для возвращения количества колонок:

```js
function getColsNum() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var num = s.getLastColumn();
  
  return num;
}
```

А вот так можно его вызвать:

```js
$(function() {
      $("window").ready(function(){
        google.script.run.getColsNum();
      })
    })
```

Только вызов его возвращает `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение в документации, для приема данных из gs, нужно добавить обработчикwithSuccessHandler(function):

```
$(function() {
      $("window").ready(function(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getColsNum();
      })
    })
```

И сама функция onSuccess:

```
function onSuccess(txt) {
       var colsNum = parseInt(txt);
       var emailSelect = document.getElementById("emailSelect");

       for (var i=1; i<=colsNum; i++) {
          var newOpt = document.createElement("option");
          newOpt.innerText = i;
          emailSelect.appendChild(newOpt);
       }
    }
```